# How do I join the most recent row from one table to another and include all rows if there isn't yet a date row?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join

I'd like to bring in just the most recent date row along with other fields from Table B that would include all values for multiple columns in Table A, even if there is no value in Table B.

The following query works, but only returns values that exist in both Table A AND in Table B.  How do I include all of A and the most recent date row of B?

Many Thanks!

```
SELECT A.person_id,
       A.second_field,
       B.create_timestamp,
       B.second_field
FROM (
  SELECT B.person_id, max(B.create_timestamp) as create_timestamp
  FROM Table_B  B
  GROUP BY B.person_id
) BMaxDate
LEFT JOIN Table_B  B
   ON BMaxDate.person_id = B.person_id AND 
      BMaxDate.create_timestamp = B.create_timestamp
LEFT JOIN Table_A  A  ON  BMaxDate.person_id = A.person_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `Table_A` as the first table in the `LEFT JOIN` operation chain:

```
SELECT A.person_id,
       A.second_field,
       B.create_timestamp,
       B.second_field
FROM Table_A AS A  
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT B.person_id, max(B.create_timestamp) as create_timestamp
   FROM Table_B  B
   GROUP BY B.person_id
) AS BMaxDate ON BMaxDate.person_id = A.person_id
LEFT JOIN Table_B AS B 
   ON BMaxDate.person_id = B.person_id AND 
      BMaxDate.create_timestamp = B.create_timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all from `table_A` and use a `left join` you have to put `table_A` first.

And for **Sql Server** you can use the with clause for more readable sub query. **Mysql** doesn't support the with clause.

```
With(
   SELECT B.person_id, max(B.create_timestamp) as create_timestamp
   FROM Table_B  B
   GROUP BY B.person_id
) AS BMaxDate
SELECT A.person_id,
       A.second_field,
       B.create_timestamp,
       B.second_field
FROM Table_A AS A  
LEFT JOIN BMaxDate ON BMaxDate.person_id = A.person_id
LEFT JOIN Table_B AS B ON BMaxDate.person_id = B.person_id 
AND BMaxDate.create_timestamp = B.create_timestamp
```